# Using latent Dirichlet allocation for information retrieval

Tags: information-retrieval

I am working on understanding various document ranking algorithms like (TF-IDF, LSI, language models, etc) by actually implementing them. I want to understand LDA and using various resources to understand the algorithm. What I don't understand is how we come up with the latent (hidden) variables/topics. Can someone please explain it to me using examples like:

```
Doc1: "shipment of gold damaged in a fire",
Doc2: "delivery of silver arrived in a silver truck", 
Doc3: "shipment of gold arrived in a truck"}; 
Query: "gold silver truck"
```

I will really appreciate any help in this regard. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

At a very high-level view, latent topics are formed from words that often appear together in the same documents.

Your examples don't have a clear set of topics, so let's use the following documents instead:

```
Doc1: After I eat my breakfast of apples, oranges, bananas, and grapes, I'm going to go snowboarding in the Alps if it's not too cold outside.
Doc2: Apples, oranges, bananas, and grapes make good smoothies.
Doc3: Apples, oranges, bananas, and grapes are tasty fruits.
Doc4: Snowboarding in the Alps is a lot of fun, but cold.
Doc5: My boyfriend lives in the Alps, where he teaches snowboarding.
```

Suppose we say there are two latent topics that we want to discover. The topics that we discover are likely to be:

- Topic 1 (the "fruit" topic): represented most strongly by `apples, oranges, bananas, grapes`.
- Topic 2 (the "Alps" topic): represented most strongly by `Alps, snowboarding, cold`.

Doc 1 is then about an equal mix of topic 1 and topic 2, docs 2-3 are mostly topic 1, docs 4-5 are mostly topic 2.

Here's an interesting example of latent dirichlet allocation applied to the WikiLeaks CableGate: http://idea.ed.ac.uk/topics/cables/browser/cables.html (The set of topics are on the left.)

Also, I wasn't sure if you wanted a high-level view or a more technical algorithmic explanation, so if it's the latter you were looking for, just say so and I can add a more technical explanation.

Comment: thanks for the response. Can you give a more technical algorithmic explanation. For example, Like given your Docs. how should I map words to documents, words to topics, etc. thanks!

Comment: Hi Raza, welcome to the site. This should have been left as a comment directly to raegtin's answer. A good way to show thanks is an upvote! Also if you are the same person whom asked the question, you should attempt to merge the accounts.

Comment: @Ali I've merged your two accounts. Please, don't forget to register your account. This will enable you to get notified by new responses/comments, earn enough rep to vote on response (>15) etc.

Comment: @Ali There's a more technical explanation here: http://blog.echen.me/2011/08/22/introduction-to-latent-dirichlet-allocation/ If you still have questions, feel free to ask more!